# Could I create a banana?

Tags: soft-question, hydrogen, matter, elements

As I understand it, until such time as stars were formed and heavier elements could be created, there was just hydrogen and helium, plus trace amounts of lithium an beryllium.

Question: if everything is derived from these fundamental building blocks, doesn't that mean, in theory at least, I could create ANYTHING, e.g. a banana?

I am aware that a banana contains acids, sugars etc, but again, isn't everything, when you get right down to it, just those fundamental elements?

Comment: Yes, everything is made out of atoms. What's the question about that?

Comment: You'd have to, at the very least, find a way to fuse nuclei together, because there is going to be a lot of carbon in those sugars.  Also, who is doing the fusing?  If its you, you have a lot of carbon too, and that doesn't come around until later after stars start fusing elements together.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - my question was pretty clear. I was pondering the notion that, if everything is made from fundamental elements that were around shortly after the big bang, and from which the others are derived, everything is therefore - in my non-expert mind - creatable. Yet I've not heard of anyone creating a banana. Sounds like a stupid question, perhaps, but I don't think it is - to a layman it's quite an interesting idea, I'd have thought.

Comment: @tmwilson - thank you, that's pretty much the sort of response I was looking for. Very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

All matter that we know is made of atoms. All atoms derived from H and He. Therefore, if a banana exists, then a banana CAN be made. YOU cannot make a banana because technology.

BONUS: Matter and energy are equivalent, therefore atoms can be produced from energy, therefore a banana can be made from energy. You cannot make a banana because technology.

Comment: Interesting - thank you. Can you elaborate on what the technological hurdles are? @tmwilson touched on them in his interesting comment, I think.

Comment: @Utkanos I think the technological hurdle would be that you have to have something supply enough energy to create the heavier elements that are in a banana from just the lighter elements.  One such "factory" is a star in a sense, and the energy is supplied from its gravitational collapse.  Making any other type of tool to do the job with just the light elements would be quite difficult (I can't think of a way that one would do that.)

Comment: @Utkanos As tmwilson said, after you had all the elements that are the building blocks of the molecules (that are the building blocks) of the banana, you would still need to correctly assembly those building blocks. We still cannot manipulate atoms that easily. Maybe the biggest challenge would be to create the elements that you would need. You would have to make a huge fusion reaction. Actually it would be interesting to estimate how much energy it would take...but I would guess that it would be more than mankind can supply.

Comment: Wow, thanks, both of you. This is really interesting. So the message I'm getting is it's simply not feasible, though not physically impossible, to create a banana (or a coconut, or an anteater, or whatever.) The idea that to create a banana would require us to harness more energy than mankind can supply, is really going to make me appreciate my breakfast more.

Comment: @Utkanos Yep. You would probably enjoy watching Cosmos (both the original with Carl Sagan and the most recent with Neil deGrasse Tyson). I thought of this because it reminded me them saying that we are all made of star stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A process of creation is seemed to be also related to language. To answer your question, let's define what a banana is in terms of shape, constituting atoms, functional properties and others. Maybe together with a banana you will need to create a banana tree by your definition, like a banana is something growing on a banana tree, or maybe not. Or imagine we have synthesised a gel that has same taste and chemical constitution as a banana, but does not posses its shape. Is it a banana?

Closer to your question, you can not create anything you want because of lack of energy.

Comment: Interesting thoughts, but I think your answer is more debate and philosophy rather than answer. Thanks anyway.